# IntelliJ IDEA - Tracking invoked methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, method-invocation

I'm working on a huge Java application using IntelliJ IDEA.
I am trying to fix some bugs and it would be extremely helpful, if I could somehow know **what methods are invoked every time I do something in the app's GUI** (for example when I press a button).

Is there any way to do that?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA community edition.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that.  You can do log tracing.  You can set breakpoints in the debugger.  IntelliJ is the best IDE in the world, but it's not a miracle worker.

Comment: Yeah, you should know at least one place in the code where you can put a breakpoint in the debugger. That way, you can examine the call stack when and if that breakpoint is _hit_. A random thread dump might help, but you have got to be unlucky. Regardless of all of that, it's helpful if you know the basic architecture of the app before fixing bug(s). The kind of reverse engineering you seem to be doing is often painful.